# jQuery - How to wrap input tag with label

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to wrap input tag with label and li tag.

```
<li><label><input type="checkbox" value="1">Apple</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" value="2">Banana</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" value="3">Orange</label></li>
```

However, Output is following...

```
<li><label><input type="checkbox" value="1">Apple</input></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" value="2">Banana</input></label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" value="3">Orange</input></label></li>
```

I can't remove `</input>`

My code:

```js
var foods = [{id:1, name:'Apple'},{id:2, name:'Banana'},{id:3, name:'Orange'}];

for(var f in foods) {
  var tag_input = $('<input type="checkbox">');
      tag_li = $('<li>')
      tag_label = $('<label>');
  tag_input.val(foods[f]['id']);
  tag_input.text(foods[f]['name']);

  var tag = tag_li.append(tag_label.append(tag_input))
  console.log(tag[0].outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're setting the `text` of the `tag_input` variable, rather than the `tag_label`.

```js
var foods = [{id:1, name:'Apple'},{id:2, name:'Banana'},{id:3, name:'Orange'}];

for(var f in foods) {
  var tag_input = $('<input type="checkbox">');
      tag_li = $('<li>')
      tag_label = $('<label>');
  tag_input.val(foods[f]['id']);
  tag_label.append(tag_input);
  tag_label.append(foods[f]['name']);
  var tag = tag_li.append(tag_label);
  console.log(tag[0].outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that I've rearranged your code a little so that the label's text comes after the checkbox, as indicated by your expected output. Basically, append the input, then the text.

Comment: To those, who might need the solution that works [up to 30 times faster](https://jsperf.com/forin-vs-reduce) and takes only one line of code instead of ten, I may suggest to take a look at my answer below.

Comment: Not very cool to post an advertisement for your own answer under someone else's. The speed gain, given the amount of data, is negligible; you could eke out more nanoseconds by mapping the array and calling `join('')` on the result, but considering the OP is using jQuery, nanosecond-level optimizations are hardly a concern.

Comment: I doubt, the actual data is 3-item array of bananas and apples. If this routine is invoked often enough (e.g. upon each incoming network request on a heavily loaded app) or against the larger data set the cumulative gain may be quite noticeable. I'm not rep-hunting (apparently, my answer scored only 1 upvote for 3 years) but rather promoting against the answers that are accepted due to perceived (often by OP exclusively, as based off their own code) lower cognitive complexity while being less performant and written in an archaic imperative manner.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to construct a string of HTML like:

```js
var foods = [{id:1, name:'Apple'},{id:2, name:'Banana'},{id:3, name:'Orange'}];
var html = "";

foods.forEach(function(o) {
  html += '<li><label><input type="checkbox" value="' + o.id + '" />' + o.name + '</label></li>';
});

console.log(html);
```

---

If you want to append the HTML string to a `<body>`, you can:

```
$("body").append(html);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the text to your `label` instead of the `input`, and `prepend` the `input`:

```js
var foods = [{id:1, name:'Apple'},{id:2, name:'Banana'},{id:3, name:'Orange'}];

for(var f in foods) {
  var tag_input = $('<input type="checkbox">');
      tag_li = $('<li>')
      tag_label = $('<label>');
  tag_input.val(foods[f]['id']);
  tag_label.text(foods[f]['name']);

  var tag = tag_li.append(tag_label.prepend(tag_input))
  console.log(tag[0].outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to put name attribute as text of input instead of text of label and hence it is adding closing tag for input.
Instead of creating new elements, you can use string to create html elements, see below code

```js
var foods = [{id:1, name:'Apple'},{id:2, name:'Banana'},{id:3, name:'Orange'}];

for(var f in foods) {
  var tag = "<li><label><input type='checkbox' value='" + foods[f]['id'] + "'>" + foods[f]['name'] +"</label></li>";
  var $tag = $(tag);
  console.log($tag.html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve your goal with one simple line of code that takes an advantage of template string and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method:

```js
const src = [{id:1, name:'Apple'},{id:2, name:'Banana'},{id:3, name:'Orange'}];

const res = src.reduce((html, {id, name}) => 
  html+=`<li><label><input type="checkbox" value="${id}">${name}</label></li>`, '');

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%}
```